# Asymptotic behaviour of fields with prime discriminant with respect to class group

Tags: nt.number-theory, asymptotics

In the original paper by Cohen - Lenstra on heuristics of class groups, they conjecture that the asymptotic number of real quadratic number fields with trivial class group is 75.446%. Since their conjectures are formulated for only the odd part of quadratic class groups, what they actually conjecture is that asymptomatically there are 75.446% of real quadratic extensions with trivial odd part for the class group.

And then they say "If we make the extra assumption that fields with prime discriminant behave like others with respect to the odd part of the class group" and based on that they conjecture the asymptotics of the trivial class groups. Of course for fields with prime discriminants the even part of the class group is trivial (from Genus theory), so the result follows from their assumption.

My question is why does it seem reasonable to make that "extra assumption".